# Laravel Echo Server for Multiple Domains

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm having a Laravel app, where multiple domains are pointing to a same code. Now I want to start laravel-echo-server for all the domains, how could I?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: When you run `laravel-echo-server`, you can specify which domains you allow to access that server in the config file. The attribute I believe is under `apiOriginAllow : { allowOrigin : 'yourdomainname.com' }`